ZK 10 Messagebox.show in doAfterCompose() stops page rendering
I am working on upgrade from ZK 8.5.2.1 to version 10, latest hotfix for jakarta.
After fixing multiple complications, I am now stuck with unexpected behaviour of Messagebox.show().
I need user to choose a Messagebox btn and then update some data in DB, based on users choice. In older version, Messagebox showed a modal window and in the meantime, my server code continued processing and pushed content to browser. So behind the Messagebox there was a fully rendered page.
Now, in ZK10, Java code continues as well, but browser is not rendering any components in the background of Messagebox.
Only thing I found in docs is deprecated use of Event thread processing which I am not using.
When I disable showing a Messagebox, page is rendered without any troubles.
What should I do to get back the expected behaviour?
fragment of Messagebox creation (only difference):
// ...doAfterCompose() - check if its read or unread and offer user to mark as read
if (!TrueFalseConverter.instance().nvlFrom(entity.getLPrectena())) {
    Messagebox.show(Labels.getLabel("diaries.make.msg.question.order.set_read.text"), Labels.getLabel("diaries.make.msg.question.order.set_read.title"), Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO, Messagebox.QUESTION, new SerializableEventListener<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            if (Messagebox.ON_YES.equals(event.getName())) {
                entity.setLPrectena(TrueFalseConverter.instance().to(Boolean.TRUE));
                app.r.ovdenObjednavkyRepository.store(entity);
            }
        }
    });
}
// ...continue with components creation and render the page


I cannot reproduce what you describe by just calling Messagebox.show() in doAfterCompose()

could you please open the browser developer tool > Console to check if there is any error message?

Could you provide HAR?
See https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/How_to_get_Efficient_Support#Provide_ZK_AU_Request.2FResponse_Details

inspect the elements behind the message box with dev tool to see if it's rendered but invisible or not rendered yet.

since the simple case doesn't produce the problem, there might be something in your case that causes the problem. You can try to comment out your code line by line to see which part cause the problem.



I gave up and replaced usage of Messagebox with my custom modal window and everything works as expected. I am not sure that during my workload I'll be able to provide more detail
